# Smoothly animate the beating effect to normal scale

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a simple beating effect using CSS keyframes and it works with `Start` and `Stop` functions:

```js
function Start() {
    const original = document.getElementById('original');
    original.classList.add("beaton-short");
}


function Stop() {
    const original = document.getElementById('original');
    original.classList.remove("beaton-short");
    original.classList.add("beatoff");
}


setTimeout(() => {
        Start();
        setTimeout(() => Stop(), 5000);
},3500);
```

```css
#original {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.beaton-short {
    -webkit-animation: beaton-short 1.5s ease-in-out infinite both;
            animation: beaton-short 1.5s ease-in-out infinite both;
}

@keyframes beaton-short {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.97);
            transform: scale(0.97);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.beatoff {
 /* animation-iteration-count: 1;*/
  animation: beatoff 0.2s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

@keyframes beatoff {
  100% { transform: scale(1) }
}
```

```html
<div class="label-container">
        <span id="original"> This text should stop beating smoothly not with a jerking movment </span>
</div>
```

As you see, in some cases, when we call `Stop`, the animation beating stops with a jerky movement to its initial scale.

Is there any solution to smoothly animate the beating back to normal without jumping?

Comment: `cubic-bezier` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function

Comment: https://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67

Comment: it's not about easing ... please look at the jumping movement at stop...